# Probability of multiple sampling from a set

Tags: probability

I have a large number of records in a database that I regularly update from an external data source. I can't filter the external data source by the last modified date, but I can get a record by id.
So I track the dates when records were updated in my database, and every day I request updates from the external data source for the records that were updated more than 30 days ago.

This guarantees that the external data source is not overloaded and my database has records that were updated at least one month ago.

I also added a random factor, and for 1% of the records, I request an update even if they were updated less than a month ago.

Now I am thinking, what is the optimal probability for random "forced updates"? I.e., if the probability was 50% and I did it only two times, on the first iteration, I would have 50% of records updated. However, on the second iteration, I update the same set, there 50% are already updated, and I randomly update 50% of the records. So in the worst case, I would update the same 50% of records; and in the best case, I would update the other 50%. But most probably, it will be around 75% of recently updated records.

I am looking for a generic formula that can answer the question of how many records will most probably be updated if I use a particular probability factor and a particular number of update iterations.

To formalize the question:

Let's take a set of $a$ items.
Let's take $b$ iterations.
On each iteration, touch $c$ random items from the set.
Each item can be touched only once in an iteration but multiple times through all iterations.

What is the most probable number of touched items after all iterations will complete?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Why use so many bullet points?

Comment: @Shaun, sorry, I tried to formalize the question in an abstract way to not bore you with the details. But I just updated it according to your comments. Hope it's better now.

Comment: Thank you for making an effort, but you still use bullet points strangely, and you haven't used MathJax.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the question was closed despite the fact that I provided the context, used MathJax, and even removed the bullet points (which is not required in the guidelines). But I'm thankful to the user who provided the answer. Indeed, considering the probability of untouched items makes the problem more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each operation leaves a proportion $p$ of items untouched, then the proportion of items left untouched after $n$ iterations is $p^n$ (approximately, with high probability, assuming your samples are independent, etc.).

E.g. if each operation touches 10% of the items, then after 5 iterations, the number of untouched items is about $(.9)^5\approx.59$ of the total.

Comment: Thank you, @Karl.